# Assign maximum and minimum values from a column if a condition is met

Tags: r

I got a data frame such as this but without the last two columns (In , Out).
I want to create the "In", column and assign the minimum value from the admission column if the value in "hosp" column is 1. Similarly, create the Out column and if the value in hosp column is 1, assign it the maximum value from the discharged column. The final data with the required In and Out column should like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admission = c("2002/02/13", 
"2002/03/05", "2002/04/04", "2002/04/05", "2002/05/30", "2002/07/20", 
"2003/02/11", "2003/02/17", "2007/02/20", "2007/07/03", "2007/07/23", 
"2007/08/03"), discharged = c("2002/02/26", "2002/04/04", "2002/04/05", 
"2002/05/30", "2002/07/02", "2002/07/23", "2003/03/14", "2003/03/19", 
"2007/02/28", "2007/07/23", "2007/08/02", "2007/08/05"), hosp = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), In = c("2002/02/13", "2002/03/05", 
"2002/03/05", "2002/03/05", "2002/05/30", "2002/07/20", "2003/02/11", 
"2003/02/17", "2007/02/20", "2007/07/03", "2007/07/03", "2007/08/03"
), Out = c("2002/02/26", "2002/05/30", "2002/05/30", "2002/05/30", 
"2002/07/02", "2002/07/23", "2003/03/14", "2003/03/19", "2007/02/28", 
"2007/08/02", "2007/08/02", "2007/08/05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I tried using the min() function, but it assign the minimum value when the hosp column has 0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date columns to `Date` class and then do the `replace`ment with the `min/max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(admission = ymd(admission), discharged = ymd(discharged)) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(In2 = replace(admission, as.logical(hosp),
     min(admission[as.logical(hosp)])),
    Out2 = replace(discharged, as.logical(hosp), 
        max(discharged[as.logical(hosp)]))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 8
      id admission  discharged  hosp In         Out        In2        Out2      
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <date>     <date>    
 1     1 2002-02-13 2002-02-26     0 2002/02/13 2002/02/26 2002-02-13 2002-02-26
 2     1 2002-03-05 2002-04-04     1 2002/03/05 2002/05/30 2002-03-05 2002-05-30
 3     1 2002-04-04 2002-04-05     1 2002/03/05 2002/05/30 2002-03-05 2002-05-30
 4     1 2002-04-05 2002-05-30     1 2002/03/05 2002/05/30 2002-03-05 2002-05-30
 5     1 2002-05-30 2002-07-02     0 2002/05/30 2002/07/02 2002-05-30 2002-07-02
 6     1 2002-07-20 2002-07-23     0 2002/07/20 2002/07/23 2002-07-20 2002-07-23
 7     1 2003-02-11 2003-03-14     0 2003/02/11 2003/03/14 2003-02-11 2003-03-14
 8     1 2003-02-17 2003-03-19     0 2003/02/17 2003/03/19 2003-02-17 2003-03-19
 9     2 2007-02-20 2007-02-28     0 2007/02/20 2007/02/28 2007-02-20 2007-02-28
10     2 2007-07-03 2007-07-23     1 2007/07/03 2007/08/02 2007-07-03 2007-08-02
11     2 2007-07-23 2007-08-02     1 2007/07/03 2007/08/02 2007-07-03 2007-08-02
12     2 2007-08-03 2007-08-05     0 2007/08/03 2007/08/05 2007-08-03 2007-08-05
```

Comment: And Can we then just get rid of those newly created duplicated columns but keeping in mind there might be same date for other ids. So, I think to group by id and then only for those ids get the unique dates in the In2.

Comment: @kamrankhan here, the only reason I created duplicate columns is to show the comparison of your expected with the new columns

Comment: @kamrankhan it is already grouped by 'id' if you chekck my code `group_by(id)`

Comment: How would you get the unique values in this case?

Comment: @kamrankhan I didn't get your question.  Isn't this question about changing to `min/max` for those hosp that are 1

Comment: @kamrankhan your query is not clear.  Do you need `df1 %>% distinct(admission, discharged)`

Comment: Yes, i meant to get the distinct values but its ok, that worked. Thank you.